# How to reduce the nested block dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have sample dictionary is below

How to reduce the Loop because Its more than 5 blocks and pylint its failing

Below are the conditions need to checked

- Checking whether People Key exists
- if 'People' exist then looping
- checking whether 'role_id' exists in People
- return base dictionary id  if role_id is None
- checking Role is available in event dictionary
- if Role not available  then pass base Developer
- if Role key present then take roleName from the Role
- If 'Tester' == roleName available then create a new dictionary

  ```
  event =  {
    "id": "100",
    "Dept": "Developer",
    "Role": [{
            "id": "201",
            "roleName": "UI"
        },
        {
            "id": "202",
            "roleName": "Tester"
        }
    ],
    "People": [{
        "id": "290",
        "fullName": "Jo",
        "email": "jo@test.com",
        "role_id": [{
                "S": "201"
            },
            {
                "S": "202"
            }
        ]
    }]
  ```

  }

Code is below which is working

```
def get_dict(event):
    total_list = ['Tester','Developer']
    Developer = {'id':None}
    if 'People' in event:  #Checking whether People Key exists
        for people in event['People']: # if 'People' exist then looping
            if people['role_id'] is None: #checking whether 'role_id' exists
                return Developer  #return base dictionary id role_id None
            for role_id in people['role_id']: #if not None 
                if 'Role' not in event: #checking ROle is available in event dictionary
                    return Developer  #if not then pass base Developer
                for role in event['Role']: #if Role key present
                    if role['id'] == role_id['S']:
                        role_name = role['roleName']
                        if role_name in total_list:
                            if "Tester" == role_name:
                                Developer = {'id': event['People'][0]['id'],
                                            'role':role_name}
    return Developer
    get_dict(event)
```

My output and Expected

```
{'id': '290', 'role': 'Tester'}
```

My Problem I am facing. How to reduce the Loop because Its more than 5 blocks and pylint its failing

Comment: The code will exit immediately if the first `people` doesn't have a `role_id` - is that the intention?

Comment: @snakecharmerb  yes